# microsoft visual c++ 10.0 is required

Tags: c++, python-3.x, cryptography

my current OS is Windows 11 Pro - 64 bit ( Version: 21H2 )

I need to work on a python project that requires python 3.4.3 and django 2.0.3
my problem is the project also requires me to install `cryptography==2.4.1` which requires microsoft visual c++ 10.0.

I've tried almost all the possible solution on stackoverflow that speak of a similar problem. But most of them are regarding windows 7. None of them seem to work for windows 11.

I've tried installing visual basic 10.0, 14.0, have also tried `set VS100COMNTOOLS=%VS140COMNTOOLS%` but nothing works.

Is ther anything else that I can do?

Comment: Install VC++ 10 Redistributable? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26999

Comment: ***I've tried installing visual basic 10.0*** Visual Basic has nothing to so with c++. You most likely need to install the Visual Studio 2010 redistributable.

Comment: @EylM : the link you provided leads to download of these 3 exe files : `vcredist_x64.exe, vcredist_ia64.exe, vcredist_x86.exe` . I've already tried this, still getting the same error

Comment: You don't want the `vcredist_ia64.exe` version. I doubt you have an Itanium CPU.

Comment: @drescherjm: thank you for pointing that point. Can you also please help me with the correct steps ?

Comment: Your python project is in a virtual environment, correct?

Comment: yes. i need to install `cryptography==2.4.1` in my virtual environment